# how to create connection pool in scala using mysql with play 2.2

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

i am using mysql in scala with play 2.2 and want to create a connection pool. I am recently find myself unable to get the code of creating connection pool. help...

Comment: FYI https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Comment: To add to om-nom-nom's comment, http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/ is another viable option.  PS, generally on SO you should at least show your past efforts/research and aim for a more specific question than "how do I do X"

Comment: Play already has connection pooling. You can get a connection with play.api.db.DB withConnection or withTransaction.

Comment: @IvanMeredith perhaps, that is the best answer. Dare to post it below?

Answer (score 2):

As Ivan Meredith said, play already comes with a connection pool, (bonecp by default), so if you configure database access as described in the play docs (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDatabase) the connections from withConnection or withTransaction will come from the connection pool.

If you want to fine-tune the connection pool almost everything seems to be supported in the config but I cannot find any docs on it so you might have to dive into the sources to find the configuration file property names.

Default configuration in Play 2.2 creates 1 partition with 5-30 connections.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-jdbc/src/main/scala/play/api/db/DB.scala

Comment: Actually, i am executing about 16 queries simultaneously via actors on mysql in play. and The problem i am facing is that TIMEOUT ERROR of mysql. i increased the maxconnections quite above than the number of queries to be executed But it still comes.